# Selenium-Webdriver Ruby --> How to wait for images to be fully loaded after click

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to Ruby and Selenium-Webdriver, so please, help :)

I am trying to open email campaign , sent to my inbox, that has images and take a screenshot in the firefox. But i can not make it wait until images is fully loaded. Once i click on 'Show images' , screenshot is already taken , but image is not loaded at that time. How can i pause the script and take screenshot some time later, after all images is displayed?

Please, help :(

Bellow is my script:

```
enter code here

require 'selenium-webdriver'

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

#==========================================================================================

wait = browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 15
#==========================================================================================
url = 'https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?.intl=us&.src=ym'
# Open browser (firefox)
browser.navigate.to url
browser.find_element(:id, 'username').send_keys "some yahoo id"
browser.find_element(:id, 'passwd').send_key "some password"
browser.find_element(:id, ".save").click
browser.find_element(:id, "inbox-label").click
browser.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@class='subj']").click
browser.find_element(:xpath, "//a[@title='Display blocked images']").click

result_page_title = browser.find_element(:tag_name, 'title')
    puts "Title of the page: \t\t: #{result_page_title.text}"
    browser.save_screenshot "1.jpg"
```

Comment: Is the code complete? Looks like there is at least an `end` statement missing at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Implicit Wait and Explicit Wait` to wait for a particular Web Element until it appears in the page. The wait period you can define and that is depends upon the application.

**Explicit Wait:**

An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. If the condition achieved it will terminate the wait and proceed the further steps.

Code:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(strEdit)));
```

Or

```
 WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
 .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
@Override
public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
    return d.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
}});
```

This waits up to 30 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if it finds the element will return it in 0 - 30 seconds. WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully. A successful return is for ExpectedCondition type is Boolean return true or not null return value for all other ExpectedCondition types.

You can use ExpectedConditions class as you need for the application.

**Implicit Wait:**

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available

Code:

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

One thing to keep in mind is that once the implicit wait is set - it will remain for the life of the WebDriver object instance

For more info use this link http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

The above code is in `Java`. Change as your language need.

Comment: This answer may be valid for Java, but simply adding "Change as your language need" doesn't answer the Ruby-specific question

Comment: [visibilityOfElementLocated](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) checks for height and width of the element to be greater than 0. It does **not** wait until the element is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby code from [the docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) (click on the 'ruby' button):

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
begin
  element = wait.until { driver.find_element(:id => "some-dynamic-element") }
ensure
  driver.quit
end
```

Which works for me

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above answer, here is how I use implicit and explicit wait in Ruby.

**Implicit Wait**

I pass this option to Selenium::WebDriver after initializing with a couple of lines like this:

```
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
```

Just replace "10" with the number of seconds you'd like the browser to wait for page refreshes and other such events.

**Explicit Wait**

There are two steps to declaring an explicit wait in Selenium.  First you set the timeout period by declaring a wait object, and then you invoke the wait with Selenium::Webdriver's .until method.  It would look something like this, in your example:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { browser.find_element(:xpath, "//path/to/picture").displayed? }
```

This would tell the Webdriver to wait a maximum of 10 seconds for the picture element to be displayed.  You can also use .enabled? if the element you're waiting for is an interactive element - this is especially useful when you're working with Ajax-based input forms.

You can also declare an explicit wait period at the start of your script, and then reference the object again whenever you need it.  There's no need to redeclare it unless you want to set a new timeout.  Personally, I like to keep the wait.until wrapped in a method, because I know I'm going to reference it repeatedly.  Something like:

```
def wait_for_element_present( how_long=5, how, what )
  wait_for_it = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => how_long )
  wait_for_it.until { @browser.find_element(how, what) }
end
```

(I find it's easier to just declare browser as an instance variable so that you don't have to pass it to the method each time, but that part's up to you, I guess?)

Answer (score 1):

ExpectedConditions isn't supported yet in the [Ruby Selenium bindings](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits).  This snippet below does the same thing as ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable — clickable just means "visible" and "enabled".

```
element = wait_for_clickable_element(:xpath => xpath)

def wait_for_clickable_element(locator)
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)

  element = wait.until { @driver.find_element(locator) }
  wait.until { element.displayed? }
  wait.until { element.enabled? }

  return element
end
```

Comment: In my case, this won't help since there is a layer on the top of it, so i have to wait until the layer disappears.

Comment: If you are confident about the time boundary in which the layer is expected to disappear, a hard-coded sleep is a valid option.  The prevailing wisdom among the Selenium community is that sleep should always be avoided, but I believe that hard-coded sleeps generally only account for a small percentage of the avoidable delay time in test executions, so if the engineering effort required to avoid them becomes unwieldy, they're okay.  Also, if you're able to locate the layer that is disappearing then you should be able to wait for the attribute change when it disappears