# Actions and htmlunitdriver - speed issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, xpath

My web application has menus that open on MouseOver. I'm writing tests using htmlunitdriver.

Test code to trigger menu is

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/index.html')]"));
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    builder.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/submenuitem')]")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

When I run a single test, it passes just fine. But when I try to run all my 80 tests at once, I get

unable to locate node using //a[starts-with(@href,'/submenuitem'

I guess the submenu is not yet open, htmlunitdriver has too much speed. Somethimes a "You may only interact with elements that are visible is occured on single runs too. Can someone help me fix this issue? Using FirefoxDriver or so is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a manual Thread.sleep(time) to wait for selenium actions is a dirty solution and should not be used at all.

Instead you could run a check is the element is visible before interacting with it.

```
public void waitUntilVisible(WebDriver driver, WebElement element){
    WebDriverWait waiting = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    waiting.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}

public void waitUntilClickable(WebDriver driver, By locator){
    WebDriverWait waiting = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    waiting.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
}

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/index.html')]"));

waitUntilVisible(driver, menu);
builder.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();

WebElement menuItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/submenuitem')]"));

waitUntilClickable(driver, By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/submenuitem')]"));
menuItem.click();
```

Comment: Is there a sifnificant difference in clickable and visibilityOf?

Comment: _elementToBeClickable_ does _visibilityOf_ check **and** checks that the element is enabled (for buttons, inputs).

Comment: Can I assume that using clickable e.g. on li-tag causes error?

Comment: It won't cause an error because checking for isEnabled on any other element does nothing. So, for <li>, waitUntilClickable and waitUntilVisible are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `implicit wait` after finding the `submenu` item. I think there is no use for implicit wait there. The most advisable place to use the implicit wait is to declare after initializing the `Driver instance`.

One More solution you can use `Explicit Wait` to wait for an element in the Page.

Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700123/selenium-webdriver-ruby-how-to-wait-for-images-to-be-fully-loaded-after-clic/14701534#14701534) for more info about the Selenium waits.