# HtmlUnitDriver and MouseOver

Tags: selenium, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

My problem with "you may only interact with elements that are currently visible" error, descriped better here [Actions and htmlunitdriver - speed issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750790/actions-and-htmlunitdriver-speed-issue)
is not solved by waiting. It occured to me that how can I be sure that the .perform -operation is doing the right thing here, since htmlunitdriver goes into invisible browser? Is there a way to assert these kind of things?

Answer (score 0):

try to print pageSource() before opening URL which your testing may be you are unable to access the URL it self

```
  System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
  driver.get("");
```

Comment: I have also same problem my firewall blacks if i open url through Html Unit driver so better to print page source and look for the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use fiddler to view the page.