# HtmlUnitDriver and css hover

Tags: selenium, htmlunit

I'm still getting back to my pop menu presented here [Actions and htmlunitdriver - speed issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750790/actions-and-htmlunitdriver-speed-issue)

(I'm not using Thread.sleep anymore though)

It is the .perform()-line that causes all the trouble. I have javascript on. Now, after some googling, it looks like htmlunitdriver does not support css hover and my popup menu uses it! Is it really so? Is there any way to test these features elseway??