# Selenium - Leave webdriver click after 10 seconds

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Do you know a way to execute an action for a limited duration?
In my case I am using webdriver.
when I validate a form action is well done but the page runs in a loop. I would like to after clicking wait 10 seconds and then force a refresh of the page.

```
// action that I would leave after 10 seconds
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();    

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

I would, after clicking, go to the next step after 10 sec because the treatment is blocked because no answer, I want it to go to the next line even if no answer.

Thanks for ur help.

Comment: I think you can make use of `Explicitly waits` or you can also make use of `Thread.sleep(10000)`. I will prefer explicit wait over thread.

Answer (score 3):

Use only Thread.sleep(10000) for waiting after the submit is clicked to refresh the next action to perform, because when you use implicit wait or explicit wait, it will not wait for 10 seconds. It wait until the next action button is visible to it. It may be 2seconds or 5seconds or 8 seconds depending on response time from the server. So better use Thread.sleep(10000).

Comment: I agree with this answer, if you don't care about whether another object appears or not, but just want to wait for 10 seconds, best thing to do is Thread.Sleep.In such case, you don't need the statement that sets implicit wait. However, if you need to look if certain object appears, then you can use implicitwait. The reason is the implicit wait time only works when you use findelement or findelements method on an object.

Comment: @Buddha - yes, you are correct Implicit wait time only works when we use findelement or findelements methods.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much preferred if you just wait for an element on the page to load after executing the refresh. This means you aren't **always** waiting 10 seconds and will just continue your actions post page reload.
Alternatively, Thread.Sleep(10000) will wait 10 seconds as Smit suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using the `Thread.sleep()` is not a advisable one. You can make use of the Selenium `Implicit Wait` and `Explicit Wait`.

See the post for [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700123/selenium-webdriver-ruby-how-to-wait-for-images-to-be-fully-loaded-after-clic/14701534#14701534).

Comment: Sorry i m new, I tried this but don't work: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30); wait.until(driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click());

Comment: Just clarify me. You want 10 seconds gap to `refresh` a page after clicking the button.am i right?

Comment: I would, after clicking, go to the next step after 10 sec because the treatment is blocked because no answer, I want it to go to the next line even if no answer.