# Explicit wait for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Working on the method trying to understand the explicit wait.

```
    require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'cucumber'

$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
$driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3

    Then /^do search$/ do
  driver = $driver
  one_way = driver.find_element(:id, "search.ar.type.code.oneWay").click
    sleep 5
   from = driver.find_element :xpath => "//div[@class = 'origin column1']//input[@type = 'text']"
   from.click
```

So after `one_way` radio button is clicked and input form changed , so I put `sleep 5` to give it a time element to appear, otherwise would be error "element not visible ...". So I thought it would be good time to understand explicit wait, because I need to wait till element will appear.

```
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 40)
  wait.until {from = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@class = 'origin column1']//input[@type = 'text']")
  from.click
  }
```

But getting error "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" . Why this code doesn't wait till element appears and click it?

Comment: See the 1st code snippet in the following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14701534/2998271)

Comment: @har07 , thanks. I saw that where did some research, but I'm trying to understand how to interact with element using click command

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the element isn't in the DOM yet, hence your needing to put a time delay in there.

That said, the API [doco for ruby](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference) says you should do it this way

```
require 'rubygems' # not required for ruby 1.9 or if you installed without gem
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading"

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
begin
  element = wait.until { driver.find_element(:id => "some-dynamic-element") }
ensure
  driver.quit
end
```

note that the element that you can then `.click()` is assigned from the wait.until method not the find_element() method as in your code.

However that arbitrary delays don't always work, if the site is busy then the delay may not be long enough.
A better option is to wait for the element to become clickable or visible.

The Java API's have [ExpectedConditions convenience methods](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) that cn be used like this...

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
element.click();
```

Unfortunatly I don't think Ruby has this yet. You may need to code up your own `ExpectedCondition` class or package.

I'm not a Ruby dev but here is the idea of a function in Java that could be used to implement your ExpectedCondition

```
public WebElement findElementInTime(WebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        log.debug("==================+>>>>>> looking for element for "+ timeoutInSeconds + " seconds");
        WebElement ret = null;

        for (int second = 0; second < timeoutInSeconds; second++) {
            try { if (isElementPresent(driver,by)) {
                log.debug("found element :-)");
                ret = driver.findElement(by);
                break;
            }} catch (Exception e) {

                log.debug("oops... sleeping 1 sec wait for button");
            }
            log.debug("sleeping 1 sec wait for button");
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, it gives me some idea so I will keep looking!

Comment: Can someone say, what is the "begin - ensure - end"? and why it's been used here?
thank you, for your response. :)