# Java - Selenium Webdriver - Ruby bindings - Missing features and functions

Tags: java, ruby, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Is it true all Java Selenium webdriver features not available in Ruby. Can anyone point me where I can find what all Java Selenium web driver can do  and Ruby Selenium-Web driver cannot. For example I can see logging, whereas Ruby has no logging. Is it published anywhere. If so it would be good to start a tabular form where we can see this - it will help focus translation efforts from java to other bindings by open community

Comment: ExpectedConditions  is not supported [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700123/selenium-webdriver-ruby-how-to-wait-for-images-to-be-fully-loaded-after-clic/29903931#29903931]

Answer (score 0):

This is the Selenium [code repository](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium). It states that all versions of Selenium must be compliant with [W3C WebDriver specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webdriver/raw-file/tip/webdriver-spec.html).  So perhaps your question could be rephrased as "what features are in the Selenium Java bindings that are not defined in the W3C Selenium standard?"

The [Java API](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html) lists all the classes.  There is nothing similar for Ruby.  Just listing all the Ruby Classes would be a help.