# Wait for an image to be fully loaded Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I saw that there is a question: [Selenium-Webdriver Ruby --> How to wait for images to be fully loaded after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700123/selenium-webdriver-ruby-how-to-wait-for-images-to-be-fully-loaded-after-clic)

But it seems that nobody has directly answered that: I need to wait for an image to be fully loaded, not just to present in the DOM, using selenium WebDriver. What should I do?Currently I'm using

```
  public static void waitUntilVisible(WebDriver webDriver, By locator) {
    WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TIMEOUT);
    driverWait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
  }
```

which uses

```
  /**
   * An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible.
   * Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is
   * greater than 0.
   *
   * @param locator used to find the element
   * @return the WebElement once it is located and visible
   */
  public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOfElementLocated(
    final By locator) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
      @Override
      public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          return elementIfVisible(findElement(locator, driver));
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
          return null;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "visibility of element located by " + locator;
      }
    };
  }
```

but if an image has already an height and width it's probably counted as visible even if the image hasn't loaded

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 8):

You could execute some javascript to interrogate the DOM. Specifically, the `complete` property of an [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

```
public static void waitUntilVisible(WebDriver webDriver, By locator) {
    WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TIMEOUT);
    WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(locator);
    driverWait.until(
        new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
            public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete", el);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

But note that `complete`:

> Returns a Boolean that is true if the browser has finished fetching
>   the image, whether successful or not. It also shows true, if the image
>   has no src value.

Comment: I want to point out that in C# this method returns a String with the word "false" or "true" depending on the status of the image, just don't forget to parse it to Boolean before returning it otherwise it won't work