# How to wait in selenium java until all images on the webpages are loaded properly

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to take a screenshot of a webpage when all images are fully loaded in it.

Although I think the solution is already available on stack overflow but none of them is working for me. the most closest solution I found is here: [Wait for an image to be fully loaded Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655802/wait-for-an-image-to-be-fully-loaded-selenium-webdriver)

however in this code and arg written in javascript executer is not returning boolean output and that is why it is giving me an error.

Following code I am using but it is given in me compile time error as "Incompatible operand types Object and 
 int" using equals is also not working for me here

```
 waitexternal.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>(){
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver ldriver) {
        ldriver = driver;
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  

        return js.executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0;

        //return (js.executeScript("return arguments[0]").equals("complete"));
        }
    }

   );
```

Comment: why don't you us `executeScript("return arguments[0].complete", el)` like in the question you refered to?

Comment: Because it is giving me compile time error... the return type of the arg mentioned is not boolean

Answer (score 4):

You can identify all the images in a current page using `document.images`. You can check how many images are there in the current page using `document.images.length`.

And to check those images are loaded properly or not, you can apply `complete` property on each image like this `document.images[0].complete` which will return true if the image is loaded otherwise false.

[image: Here the proof]

Below is the code which will check the `DOM` is loaded or not first then if the DOM is loaded, it will wait until all the images are loaded in that page.

```
// Launching the browser
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

// Declaring and Casting driver to JavaScriptExecutor
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
// Getting DOM status
Object result = jse.executeScript("return document.readyState;");
System.out.println("=> The status is : "+result.toString());
// Checking DOM loading is completed or not?
if(result.equals("complete")) {
    // Fetching images count
    result = jse.executeScript("return document.images.length");
    int imagesCount = Integer.parseInt(result.toString());
    boolean allLoaded = false;
    // Checking and waiting until all the images are getting loaded
    while(!allLoaded) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<imagesCount;i++) {
            result = jse.executeScript("return document.images["+i+"].complete;");
            boolean loaded = (Boolean) result;
            if(loaded) count++;
        }
        // Breaking the while loop if all the images loading completes
        if(count == imagesCount) {
            System.out.println("=> All the Images are loaded...");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("=> Not yet loaded...");
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

But careful while using the above code because it may go to an infinity state sometimes if the element is not loaded at all.

To check a particular element is loaded or not, you can do like below :

```
// To check a particular element is loaded or not?
WebElement googleLogo = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));
boolean loaded = (Boolean) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].complete;", googleLogo);
System.out.println("The google logo is loaded ? "+loaded);
```

To wait until that particular image is loaded, you can do like below :

```
// To check a particular element is loaded or not?
WebElement googleLogo = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));
while(!(Boolean) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].complete;", googleLogo)) {
    System.out.println("=> The google logo is not yet loaded...");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
System.out.println("The google logo is loaded... ");
```

To learn more about the JavaScript commands and the JavaScriptExecutor, check out and do subscribe to [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UghwIKHB8Wo&list=PLzIX4GKTh5quMkUB32JKpknaHzTnaAFOe)

Source : [HTML DOM images Collection](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_images.asp), [Document.images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images)

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code. I am using it and it's working for me.

```
public Boolean verifyImageLoad() throws Exception {
     wait.until(
             new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>(){
                    @Override
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete", imageWebElementHere);
                    }
                }
            );
    if (!imageWebElementHere.getAttribute("naturalWidth").equals("0")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```